# awk/sed/perl one liner to edit json file

Tags: command-line, awk, sed, perl, json

We want to add the folwing lines:

```
export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx8g -Xms8g"
```

and:

```
export KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS=" -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 - XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M-XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 - XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80"
```

in "content" line

can we get suggestion how to edit the file with awk,sed,perl one liner , etc

example of the json before update

```
{
  "href" : "http://master02:8080/api/v1/clusters/HDP/configurations?type=kafka-env&tag=version1527250007610",
  "items" : [
    {
      "href" : "http://master02:8080/api/v1/clusters/HDP/configurations?type=kafka-env&tag=version1527250007610",
      "tag" : "version1527250007610",
      "type" : "kafka-env",
      "version" : 8,
      "Config" : {
        "cluster_name" : "HDP",
        "stack_id" : "HDP-2.6"
      },
      "properties" : {
        "content" : "\n#!/bin/bash\n\n# Set KAFKA specific environment variables here.\n\n# The java implementation to use.\nexport JAVA_HOME={{java64_home}}\nexport PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin\nexport PID_DIR={{kafka_pid_dir}}\nexport LOG_DIR={{kafka_log_dir}}\nexport KAFKA_KERBEROS_PARAMS={{kafka_kerberos_params}}\nexport JMX_PORT=9997\n# Add kafka sink to classpath and related depenencies\nif [ -e \"/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink.jar\" ]; then\n  export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink.jar\n  export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/lib/*\nfi\n\nif [ -f /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-ranger-env.sh ]; then\n. /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-ranger-env.sh\nfi",
        "is_supported_kafka_ranger" : "true",
        "kafka_log_dir" : "/var/log/kafka",
        "kafka_pid_dir" : "/var/run/kafka",
        "kafka_user" : "kafka",
        "kafka_user_nofile_limit" : "128000",
        "kafka_user_nproc_limit" : "65536"
      }
    }
  ]
```

expected output ( example of the json after update )

```
{
  "href" : "http://master02:8080/api/v1/clusters/HDP/configurations?type=kafka-env&tag=version1527250007610",
  "items" : [
    {
      "href" : "http://master02:8080/api/v1/clusters/HDP/configurations?type=kafka-env&tag=version1527250007610",
      "tag" : "version1527250007610",
      "type" : "kafka-env",
      "version" : 8,
      "Config" : {
        "cluster_name" : "HDP",
        "stack_id" : "HDP-2.6"
      },
      "properties" : {
        "content" : "\n#!/bin/bash\n\n# Set KAFKA specific environment variables here.\n\n# The java implementation to use.\nexport JAVA_HOME={{java64_home}}\nexport PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin\nexport PID_DIR={{kafka_pid_dir}}\nexport LOG_DIR={{kafka_log_dir}}\nexport KAFKA_KERBEROS_PARAMS={{kafka_kerberos_params}}\nexport JMX_PORT=9997\n# Add kafka sink to classpath and related depenencies\nif [ -e \"/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink.jar\" ]; then\n  export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink.jar\n  export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/lib/*\nfi\n\nif [ -f /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-ranger-env.sh ]; then\n. /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-ranger-env.sh\nfi\nexport KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=\"-Xmx8g -Xms8g\"\nKAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS=\"-XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 - XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M-XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 - XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80\n"",
        "is_supported_kafka_ranger" : "true",
        "kafka_log_dir" : "/var/log/kafka",
        "kafka_pid_dir" : "/var/run/kafka",
        "kafka_user" : "kafka",
        "kafka_user_nofile_limit" : "128000",
        "kafka_user_nproc_limit" : "65536"
      }
    }
  ]
```

**other example of the content line after update**

```
 "content" : "\n#!/bin/bash\n\n# Set KAFKA specific environment variables here.\n\n# The java implementation to use.\nexport JAVA_HOME={{java64_home}}\nexport PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin\nexport PID_DIR={{kafka_pid_dir}}\nexport LOG_DIR={{kafka_log_dir}}\nexport KAFKA_KERBEROS_PARAMS={{kafka_kerberos_params}}\nexport JMX_PORT=9997\n# Add kafka sink to classpath and related depenencies\nif [ -e \"/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink.jar\" ]; then\n  export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink.jar\n  export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/lib/*\nfi\n\nif [ -f /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-ranger-env.sh ]; then\n. /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-ranger-env.sh\nfi\nexport KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=\"-Xmx8g -Xms8g\"\nKAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS=\"-XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 - XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M-XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 - XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80\n"",
```

Comment: What happened to `export`?

Comment: and why does the shell script start with a new-line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a one-liner, but ...

```
$ new_lines='\\nexport KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=\\"-Xmx8g -Xms8g\\"\\nexport KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS=\\" -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 - XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M-XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 - XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80\\"'
$ new_content=$( jq '.items[0].properties.content' file.json | sed 's/"$/'"$new_lines"'"/')
$ jq '.items[0].properties.content = '"$new_content" file.json
{
  "href": "http://master02:8080/api/v1/clusters/HDP/configurations?type=kafka-env&tag=version1527250007610",
  "items": [
    {
      "href": "http://master02:8080/api/v1/clusters/HDP/configurations?type=kafka-env&tag=version1527250007610",
      "tag": "version1527250007610",
      "type": "kafka-env",
      "version": 8,
      "Config": {
        "cluster_name": "HDP",
        "stack_id": "HDP-2.6"
      },
      "properties": {
        "content": "\n#!/bin/bash\n\n# Set KAFKA specific environment variables here.\n\n# The java implementation to use.\nexport JAVA_HOME={{java64_home}}\nexport PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin\nexport PID_DIR={{kafka_pid_dir}}\nexport LOG_DIR={{kafka_log_dir}}\nexport KAFKA_KERBEROS_PARAMS={{kafka_kerberos_params}}\nexport JMX_PORT=9997\n# Add kafka sink to classpath and related depenencies\nif [ -e \"/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink.jar\" ]; then\n  export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink.jar\n  export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/lib/*\nfi\n\nif [ -f /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-ranger-env.sh ]; then\n. /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-ranger-env.sh\nfi\nexport KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=\"-Xmx8g -Xms8g\"\nexport KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS=\" -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 - XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M-XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 - XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80\"",
        "is_supported_kafka_ranger": "true",
        "kafka_log_dir": "/var/log/kafka",
        "kafka_pid_dir": "/var/run/kafka",
        "kafka_user": "kafka",
        "kafka_user_nofile_limit": "128000",
        "kafka_user_nproc_limit": "65536"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

To verify the new content readably:

```
$ printf "$new_content\n"
"
#!/bin/bash

# Set KAFKA specific environment variables here.

# The java implementation to use.
export JAVA_HOME={{java64_home}}
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PID_DIR={{kafka_pid_dir}}
export LOG_DIR={{kafka_log_dir}}
export KAFKA_KERBEROS_PARAMS={{kafka_kerberos_params}}
export JMX_PORT=9997
# Add kafka sink to classpath and related depenencies
if [ -e "/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink.jar" ]; then
  export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink.jar
  export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/lib/*
fi

if [ -f /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-ranger-env.sh ]; then
. /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-ranger-env.sh
fi
export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx8g -Xms8g"
export KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS=" -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 - XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M-XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 - XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80""
```

Comment: @dear Glenn I will be with you honest , your solution is brilliant , but we need to do this on sites , and we not allow to install the jq command , if you have other alternative without the jq , I will happy to see it , if not I will try to ask customer to install the jq command on his linux machine 
Btw – can we download the jq command , is it one rpm ?   , I will happy to connect you by https://www.linkedin.com/in/glennjackman/

Comment: Depending on your OS, it's just `yum install jq`

Comment: not in my repo , so I need to download this jq

Comment: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Answer (score 6):

Perl solution using the [JSON](http://p3rl.org/JSON) module:

```
perl -MJSON -we '
    $json = JSON->new->pretty->canonical;
    open $fh, "<", shift or die $!;
    $j = $json->decode(do { undef $/; <$fh> });
    $j->{items}[0]{properties}{content} .= qq(\nexport KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx8g -Xms8g"\nexport KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS=" -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80");
    print $json->encode($j);
' -- file.json > new.json
```

I had to fix your expected file (`export` was missing for the second variable, plus some whitespace issues) and canonicalise it to get the exactly same output.

Comment: Choroba we get Can't locate JSON.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

Comment: is it possible to download only the JSON.pm on working folder and then remove it

Comment: Try using [JSON::PP](http://p3rl.org/JSON::PP) instead.

Comment: do you mean to install the modul - JSON::PP

Comment: JSON::PP is in core Perl since 5.14.

Comment: not so filmier with perl , so how to load this module before I run your command ? ( I have  perl -v

This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
(with 29 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Comment: Just replace both occurrences of JSON with JSON::PP in my command: `perl -MSJON::PP -we '$json = JSON::PP->new...`.

Comment: after I replaced that we get - Invalid module name JSON:PP with -M option: contains single ':'.

Comment: @yael Two colons.

Comment: perl -MJSON::PP -we '
    $json = JSON::PP->new->pretty->canonical;
    open $fh, "<", shift or die $!;
    $j = $json->decode(do { undef $/; <$fh> });
    $j->{items}[0]{properties}{content} .= qq(\nexport KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx8g -Xms8g"\nexport KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS=" -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80");
    print $json->encode($j);
' -- file.json > new.json

Comment: Can't locate JSON/PP.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

Comment: @yael: What version of Perl do you use?

Comment: This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
(with 29 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2012, Larry Wall

Comment: @yael: Your Perl installation is non-standard. It should contain the library.

Comment: can you please described the steps to locate the lib..

Comment: What OS/distribution do you use?

Comment: we are use redhat 7 , OS

Comment: And you probably only have the `perl` package, not `perl-core`. So get `perl-core` or `perl-JSON-PP` installed.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple fix with Perl appending the lines to the line (each line) with `content` without parsing the JSON doc. This is a one-liner (copy and paste into your command line). I guess you want this:

```
<in perl -nple'$_.="\\nexport KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=\"-Xmx8g -Xms8g\"\\nexport KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS=\" -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80\"\\n\"" 
if/^\s+"content"/ '
```

Here `in` at the beginning is the input file. You're getting the output on the screen, which you can adjust easily. You could also have Perl modify the file in place using the `-i` switch. (Learn about it first.)

The output is this:

```
{
  "href" : "http://master02:8080/api/v1/clusters/HDP/configurations?type=kafka-env&tag=version1527250007610",
  "items" : [
    {
      "href" : "http://master02:8080/api/v1/clusters/HDP/configurations?type=kafka-env&tag=version1527250007610",
      "tag" : "version1527250007610",
      "type" : "kafka-env",
      "version" : 8,
      "Config" : {
        "cluster_name" : "HDP",
        "stack_id" : "HDP-2.6"
      },
      "properties" : {
        "content" : "\n#!/bin/bash\n\n# Set KAFKA specific environment variables here.\n\n# The java implementation to use.\nexport JAVA_HOME={{java64_home}}\nexport PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin\nexport PID_DIR={{kafka_pid_dir}}\nexport LOG_DIR={{kafka_log_dir}}\nexport KAFKA_KERBEROS_PARAMS={{kafka_kerberos_params}}\nexport JMX_PORT=9997\n# Add kafka sink to classpath and related depenencies\nif [ -e \"/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink.jar\" ]; then\n  export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink.jar\n  export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/lib/*\nfi\n\nif [ -f /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-ranger-env.sh ]; then\n. /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-ranger-env.sh\nfi",\nexport KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx8g -Xms8g"\n export KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS=" -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80"\n"
        "is_supported_kafka_ranger" : "true",
        "kafka_log_dir" : "/var/log/kafka",
        "kafka_pid_dir" : "/var/run/kafka",
        "kafka_user" : "kafka",
        "kafka_user_nofile_limit" : "128000",
        "kafka_user_nproc_limit" : "65536"
      }
    }
  ]
```

As you can see, I did a correction here:

```
export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx8g -Xms8g"\nexport KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS=" -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80"\n
```

I changed the `-XX` option layout and the ending is `-XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80"\n`, and not `- XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80\n"`, as you required. So change this if that's what you really want. Also the newline before the shebang is what I'd remove. But I've left this for you.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` one liner.

```
$ sed -i '/"content"/s/",$/\\nexport KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=\\"-Xmx8g -Xms8g\\"\\nKAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS=\\"-XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 - XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M-XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 - XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80\\n"",/' myfile
```

Comment: 0 dependencies and the answer requested

Comment: @jas-: But it can break if the formatting of the JSON changes.

Comment: Nice and readable. Great.

Answer (score 1):

With `jq`:

```
v1='export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx8g -Xms8g"'
v2='export KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS=" -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 - XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M-XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 - XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80"'

jq --arg v1 "$v1" --arg v2 "$v2" '.items[].properties.content += $v1 + "\n" + $v2 + "\n"' infile.json
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 perl -lpe '
    BEGIN {
       my $a = q[export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx8g -Xms8g"];

       my $b = q[export KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS=" -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 - XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M-XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 - XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80"];

       push @A, s/[\\"]/\\$&/gr for $a, $b;
    }

    /^\h*"content"/ and
       $_ = 
          join q[], 
             join(q[\n], 
                split(/",?$/), @A),
             /(",?)$/;
 '    json-file
```

Working :

```
Store the data to be added in scalar variables using the single quote operator to avoid backslashing.

Change all backslashes, double quotes to their escaped versions.
```

Then in the target line, split it on  ", |,
   and join the elements plus array @A contents with the literal string \n and ending with the closing quotes.